# Pandas DF: Styling with multiple columns and condition in subset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to apply formatting on multiple columns based on filter condition. Here is my code
For example I want to apply percent style to all rows of column B, C, D where column A = "certain value".

```
create_html(
            df=df_data,
            email_columns=email_cols,
            percent_columns=pd.IndexSlice[
                df_data["A"] == "certain value",
                    "B",
                    "C",
                    "D"                 
            ])
```

My custom create_html function has below styling

```
html = (df[[*email_columns]]
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .rename(columns=email_columns)
        .style.format("{:.1%}", subset=percent_columns)
        .render()
)
return html
```

I get   *IndexingError("Too many indexers")
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers* when I run this. What am I doing wrong?

Sample data

| company | category | revenue | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test company 1 | test category 1 | 1000 | certain value | 0.65356122 | 0.64845156 | 0.653306501 |
| test company 2 | test category 2 | 2000 | no format | 22 | 36 | 38 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: In text please, pic text is  not possible copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working this trick - filtered index value which match mask and then columns are in list:

```
percent_columns = pd.IndexSlice[ df_data.index[df_data["A"] == "certain value"], 
                                 ["B","C", "D"  ] ]
styles = df_data.style.format("{:.1%}", subset=percent_columns).render()

print (styles)
<style  type="text/css" >
</style><table id="T_21a7c_" ><thead>    <tr>        <th class="blank level0" ></th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >company</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >category</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >revenue</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col3" >A</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col4" >B</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col5" >C</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col6" >D</th>    </tr></thead><tbody>
                <tr>
                        <th id="T_21a7c_level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >test company 1</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >test category 1</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >1000</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >certain value</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row0_col4" class="data row0 col4" >65.4%</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row0_col5" class="data row0 col5" >64.8%</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row0_col6" class="data row0 col6" >65.3%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <th id="T_21a7c_level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >test company 2</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >test category 2</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >2000</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row1_col3" class="data row1 col3" >no format</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row1_col4" class="data row1 col4" >22.000000</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row1_col5" class="data row1 col5" >36.000000</td>
                        <td id="T_21a7c_row1_col6" class="data row1 col6" >38.000000</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Test data:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['test company 1', 'test company 2'], 'category': ['test category 1', 'test category 2'], 'revenue': [1000, 2000], 'A': ['certain value', 'no format'], 'B': [0.65356122, 22.0], 'C': [0.64845156, 36.0], 'D': [0.653306501, 38.0]})
```

EDIT: You need default index values before `IndexSlice` for processing in next code `DataFrame` with default index:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

percent_columns = pd.IndexSlice[ df.index[df["A"] == "certain value"], 
                                 ["B","C", "D"  ] ]

html = (df[[*email_columns]]
        .rename(columns=email_columns)
        .style.format("{:.1%}", subset=percent_columns)
        .render()
)
```

EDIT1: Per groups:

```
df_all_data = df_all_data.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df_all_data)
          company         category  revenue              A          B  \
0  test company 1  test category 1     1000  certain value   0.653561   
1  test company 2  test category 2     2000      no format  22.000000   
2  test company 1  test category 1     1000  certain value   0.653561   
3  test company 2  test category 2     2000      no format  22.000000   

           C          D  E  
0   0.648452   0.653307  1  
1  36.000000  38.000000  1  
2   0.648452   0.653307  2  
3  36.000000  38.000000  2 

for (name, df_data) in df_all_data.groupby("E"):
        
    
    percent_columns = pd.IndexSlice[ df_data.index[df_data["A"] == "certain value"], 
                                     ["B","C", "D"  ] ]
    
    html = (df_data
            .style.format("{:.1%}", subset=percent_columns)
            .render()
    )
    print (html)
```

Comment: I get an error from this "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels "
KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Int64Index([105, 107, 109, 111, 119,\n            ...\n            867, 869, 875, 881, 903],\n           dtype='int64', length=36)

Is it because my function parameter percent_columns =[] ?

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - What is your pandas version?

Comment: Pandas version  1.1.5

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - Can you check test data if working? Added to answer.

Comment: works fine with the test data ..I don't know how this happens

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - One idea - is possible use `df_data = df_data.reset_index(drop=True)` for default index before my solution?

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - Added `edit` to answer.

Comment: Ok, I was running this in a for loop for grouped data 

for (name, df_data) in df_all_data.groupby("E"):

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - If reseting before it should working.

Comment: Still figuring it out.. I dropped the index as per your approach and print percent_columns
I get a tuple  value (Int64Index([ 1,  3, ...e='int64'), ["B","C", "D",..])

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - hmmm, added another `EDIT1`

Comment: its quite strange the only way I could get it to work was passing index to percent values .percent_columns=percent_columns[1]. I will drill down more on this. Thanks for your help